# Survey in PHP not saving votes correctly to txt file

Tags: php, html, pool, survey

My problem is that when I vote for for example last option in survey the .txt file with survey answers gets empty row which ruins my graph which is generated after voting.

If you want you can check the site [here](http://nwwnd.cba.pl/ankieta/)

My .txt file looks like this, each row is each pool position.

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

My index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ankieta</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Oceń poziom nauczania na swojej uczelni:
        <form action="send.php" method="GET" >
            <input type=radio name=1 value="1" checked>2<br>
            <input type=radio name=1 value="2">3<br>
            <input type=radio name=1 value="3">4<br>
            <input type=radio name=1 value="4">5<br>
            <input type=radio name=1 value="5">Nie wiem<br>
            <input type=submit value="Wyślij"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My send.php I think something might be wrong here.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ankieta</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['glos'])) {
        echo "Głos już oddano! Spróbuj za 40 sekund.";
    } else {
        echo " Dziękuję za głos! Zagłosowano na: ";
        $wyniki=file("wyniki.txt");
        switch($_GET['1']) {
            case "1":
                $wyniki[0]=$wyniki[0]+1;
                echo "2";
            break;
            case "2":
                $wyniki[1]=$wyniki[1]+1;
                echo "3";
            break;
            case "3":
                $wyniki[2]=$wyniki[2]+1;
                echo "4";
            break;
            case "4":
                $wyniki[3]=$wyniki[3]+1;
                echo "5";
            break;
            case "5":
                $wyniki[4]=$wyniki[4]+1;
                echo "Nie wiem";
            break;
        }
        $koncowo=$wyniki[0]."\n".$wyniki[1].$wyniki[2].$wyniki[3].$wyniki[4];
        file_put_contents('wyniki.txt',$koncowo);
    }
    setcookie("glos", 1, time()+40);
    ?>
    <BR>
    <form action="http://nwwnd.cba.pl/ankieta/wyniki.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Wyniki" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My wynik.php file

```
<? 
$wysokosc = 600; 
$szerokosc = 700; 
$graph = ImageCreate($szerokosc, $wysokosc); 
$bialy = ImageColorAllocate($graph,255,255,255); 
$czarny = ImageColorAllocate($graph,0,0,0); 
$rozowy = ImageColorAllocate($graph,255,233,241);
$czerwony = ImageColorAllocate($graph,255,0,0);
$fiolet = ImageColorAllocate($graph,148,0,254); 
$niebieski = ImageColorAllocate($graph,0,0,255); 
$wyniki=file("wyniki.txt");
$wynik1=$wyniki[0];
$wynik2=$wyniki[1];
$wynik3=$wyniki[2];
$wynik4=$wyniki[3];
$wynik5=$wyniki[4];
$wszystko=$wynik1+$wynik2+$wynik3+$wynik4+$wynik5;
$szer1=600*$wynik1/$wszystko;
$szer2=600*$wynik2/$wszystko;
$szer3=600*$wynik3/$wszystko;
$szer4=600*$wynik4/$wszystko;
$szer5=600*$wynik5/$wszystko;
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,0,0,$szerokosc,$wysokosc,$bialy);
Imagerectangle($graph,1,1,($szerokosc-2),($wysokosc-2),$czarny);
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,30,100,($szer1+30),130,$rozowy);
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,30,200,($szer2+30),230,$czerwony);
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,30,300,($szer3+30),330,$fiolet);
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,30,400,($szer4+30),430,$niebieski);
Imagefilledrectangle($graph,30,500,($szer5+30),530,$czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,4,($szer1+40), 100 , $wynik1 , $czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,4,($szer2+40), 200 , $wynik2 , $czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,4,($szer3+40), 300 , $wynik3 , $czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,4,($szer4+40), 400 , $wynik4 , $czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,4,($szer5+40), 500 , $wynik5 , $czarny);
Imagestring ($graph,2,30, 80 , "2" ,$czarny );
Imagestring ($graph,2,30, 180 , "3" ,$czarny );
Imagestring ($graph,2,30, 280 , "4",$czarny );
Imagestring ($graph,2,30, 380 , "5",$czarny );
Imagestring ($graph,2,30, 480 , "Nie wiem",$czarny );
imagettftext ($graph,20,0,300,60,$czarny,"arial.ttf","Ankieta");
Header("Content-type: image/png"); 
ImagePng($graph); 
ImageDestroy($graph); 
?>
```

When I vote for 5th option wyniki.txt looks like below

```
0

0
0
0
1
```

What is wrong? Where come this empty row comes?

Comment: Remove the `"\n"` in this line `$koncowo=$wyniki[0]."\n"`

Comment: Thank you sir very much!

Comment: Awww... now it makes the .txt file as '0 row 0 row 10 row 0' when voting for 3rd option. So it literally combines row 3th and 4th and at 1 to 3rd.

Comment: Only the one you select is missing the newline character?

Comment: All of them were missing newline character but I fixed it as I described in comment below. Thank you Sir, I think I accepted your answer correctly and voted it as useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `"\n"` in this line `$koncowo=$wyniki[0]."\n"`

---

Since all of your new values will need a new line you should do something like this to make sure each line is handled properly:

```
$koncowo = array($wyniki[0], $wyniki[1], $wyniki[2], $wyniki[3], $wyniki[4]);
$contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $koncowo); // add an EOL to each array member
file_put_contents('wyniki.txt',$contents);
```

Comment: Awww... now it makes the .txt file as '0 row 0 row 10 row 0' when voting for 3rd option. So it literally combines row 3th and 4th and adds 1 to 3rd. – Juliusz Urbańczyk 2 mins ago

Comment: Okay I fixed the second issue by adding " . "\n"" to every line of  $wyniki[X]=$wyniki[X]+1 . "\n";

Comment: See the edit @JuliuszUrbańczyk. You can add a newline to each using `implode()`